# AQuery image loading via proxy

Tags: android, proxy

I try to load photos using the AQuery (aka android-query) library in my android project. Here is my code:

```
public class AQueryTestActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aquery_test);

    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "some.proxy");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");

    AQuery aq = new AQuery(this);
    AQUtility.debug(true);

    aq.id(R.id.text_view).text("Text set by AQuery");

    aq.id(R.id.teaser_image).image("http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3531/3769416703_b76406f9de.jpg");
}
```

When I use

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

image loading works without problems.

Does AQuery ignore the proxy settings? Is there any way to debug this?

I use **AQUtility.debug(true)** but can not find any errors logged by android-query in the Logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that AQuery (version 0.23.16) is currently ignoring the System properties for proxy hosts.

Answer (score 0):

If **internet permission** is not given, AQuery will silently ignore it.

You may also use **AQUtility.setDebug(true);**